# DS_ABSALIGN style to avoid calculations

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

I have a tablet with a stylus, in normal operation it's easy to draw and figure out where the stylus is since hardware feeds the correct coordinates. Then i rotate the monitor 90 º via ChangeDisplaySettingsEx API, in this situation i have to apply a translation (2nd monitor) + rotation which i'd like to avoid. Then i read about this style DS_ABSALIGN in MSDN:

> Indicates that the coordinates of the dialog box are screen
>   coordinates. If this style is not specified, the coordinates are
>   client coordinates.

I'd like to draw to a DC in screen coordinates which is what i'm being feeded, not client coordinates, but defining that style doesn't make any difference.

```
//unaffected by the style
DrawIcon(hDevCtx, m_Point.x, m_Point.y, LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
```

Is it there any way to draw an icon in screen coordinates?

edit: finally i had no choice but to do the calculations for every turn so i close the question

Comment: My gut tells me that `DS_ABSALIGN` only applies to the coordinates specified in your dialog template, not to DCs created later; those would still be in client space. I wouldn't know for sure. Why are you concerned about calculations? `MapWindowPoints()` will do the screen/client conversion work for you.

Comment: just to save time :)

Comment: Time writing code? Or run time in the drawing code? If the latter, then it really won't make a difference (programs do much more complicated things in the drawing handler to begin with).

Comment: `DS_ABSALIGN` only affects the position of the dialog itself; if you create a dialog with an owner window, it will normally be positioned relative to that window, but with `DS_ABSALIGN` you can specify absolute coordinates. It doesn't affect any of the controls or rendering you do in the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates you pass to DrawIcon() depend on the kind of DC you have. For example let's say you used GetDC() to get the DC. If you pass it a window handle, the coordinates you pass to DrawIcon() will be relative to the client area of that window. If you pass 0 to GetDC() the coordinates will be relative to desktop screen. If you want to draw on desktop screen then use GetDC(0) or a better method if there is one. If you just want to convert screen coordinates to client coordinates or vice versa use ScreenToClient() or ClientToScreen()

Comment: i didn't know that feature, as soon as i can test it, i'll accept it as answer